# Injecting beans into a HttpMessageConverter in Spring Framework 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to inject a bean into a custom `HttpMessageConverter` which is registered in a configuration class:

```
package my.package.config;

import ...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "my.package" )
public class CompleteConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) {
        converters.add( this.myMessageConverter() );
        this.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters( converters );
    }

    @Bean
    public MyMessageConverter myMessageConverter() {
        MyMessageConverter mc = new MyMessageConverter();
        mc.setServiceDao( this.serviceDao() );
        return mc;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceDao serviceDao() {
        return ...;
    }

}
```

The custom HttpMessageConverter is defined as follows:

```
package my.package.converter;

public class MyMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Person> {

    private ServiceDao serviceDao;

    ...
    implementation which uses ServiceDao
    ...

    public void setServiceDao( ServiceDao s ) {
        this.serviceDao = s;
    }

    public ServiceDao getServiceDao() {
        return this.serviceDao;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as intended, because Spring internally creates a new instance of `MyMessageConverter`, not setting the `ServiceDao` for this new instance.

I tried to

- annotate `MyMessageConverter#setServiceDao( ServiceDao s )` with `@Autowired`.
- implement `BeanFactoryAware` in `MyMessageConverter`.

Both approaches didn't work. The `MyMessageConverter` object which is used to convert the HTTP message always ends up having a `null` reference stored in `MyMessageConverter#serviceDao`.

Neither Google nor the Spring Framework 3.1 documentation came up with information on that problem.

@Bob Flannigon: This is definitely not the problem. `CompleteConfiguration#myMessageConverter()` returns a correctely cofigured message converter. However, when I remove the zero-args constructor from `MyMessageConverter`, Spring throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [my.package.converter.MyMessageConverter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: my.package.converter.MyMessageConverter.<init>()
```

I guess this means that Spring creates a new instance which is then used instead of my configured bean.

Comment: In XML configuration, bean order can be important, I'm not sure if that's true for Object-based configuration, but I'd anticipate the underlying mechanism to be the same.  Have you tried simply moving the serviceDAO definition above the message convertor?

Comment: see the edit, the response was a bit longer.

Comment: I don't get it. Your `CompleteConfiguration` as it is in your current question, is fine and should create a `MyMessageConverter` with the `ServiceDao` bean coming from `serviceDao()`.

Comment: This is true, but Spring doesn't use my instance of `MyMessageConverter` to convert HTTP messages. Spring creates a new instance, using this new (now unconfigured) instance to convert HTTP messages. This is the reason why Spring throws an exception if no zero-args constructor is provided by `MyMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour vanishes after upgrading from Spring Framework 3.1.0 to Spring Framework 3.2.3.

Maybe it was just a bug.